# How to render images with React JS using map function? this code just render first slide not all slides

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, slider

> When I run the code, it only shows the first slide, but does not show the rest of slides, in this codes I want to use map function for render image slides and I use Arrow Icon for switch between slides, this code displays just the first slide and other is empty, why?
> This is my main code:

```js
import { sliderItems } from "../data";
       
    const Slider = () => {
        const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0);
        const handleClick = (direction) => {
          if (direction === "left") {
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex > 0 ? slideIndex - 1 : 2);
          }else {
            setSlideIndex(slideIndex < 2 ? slideIndex + 1 : 0);
          }
        };
        return (
          <Container>
            <Arrow direction="left" onClick={() => handleClick("left")}>
                <ArrowLeftOutlined />
            </Arrow>
    
            <Wrapper slideIndex={slideIndex}>
               {sliderItems.map((item) => (
                <Slide bg={item.bg} key={item.id}>
                  <ImgContainer>
                    <Image src={item.img} />
                  </ImgContainer>
                  <InfoContainer>
                    <Title>{item.title}</Title>
                    <Desc>{item.desc}</Desc>
                    <Button>{item.btn}</Button>
                  </InfoContainer>
                </Slide>
              ))}
            </Wrapper>    
    
    
            <Arrow direction="right" onClick={() => handleClick("right")}>
                <ArrowRightOutlined />
            </Arrow>
          </Container>
        );
    };
    
    export default Slider;
```

> This is my data file:why my code doesn't work for other slides

```
export const sliderItems = [
    
       {
         id: 1,
         img: "https://i.ibb.co/XsdmR2c/1.png",
         title: "SUMMER SALE",
         desc: "DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR NEW ARRIVALS.",
         bg: "f5fafd",
       },
       {
         id: 2,
         img: "https://i.ibb.co/DG69bQ4/2.png",
         title: "AUTUMN COLLECTION",
         desc: "DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR NEW ARRIVALS.",
         bg: "fcf1ed",
       },
       {
         id: 3,
         img: "https://i.ibb.co/cXFnLLV/3.png",
         title: "LOUNGEWEAR LOVE",
         desc: "DON'T COMPROMISE ON STYLE! GET FLAT 30% OFF FOR NEW ARRIVALS.",
         bg: "fbf0f4",
       },
    ];
```

Comment: are you using any package for slider ?

Comment: no, I did not use any package. I just used styled component for style

Comment: try using a third party slider https://swiperjs.com/react it will be much easier